# How to move an object in particular direction with specific distance in three.js

Tags: three.js

I need to move an object along directional vector through some distance. I fount translateOnAxis(vector, distance) of Object3D class. But I'm not able to understand how it works.
    I've an object- sphere. I'm scaling it to look like ellipse. And setting position and direction. Now I need this object to move in the same direction which I'm setting it to, through some distance. When I apply it, I can't see the object. Can anybody suggest how it can be achieved?

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 64, 64, 0, -Math.PI );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, 1, zScale );    //scaling it to look like ellipse
var direction = new THREE.Vector3( xDir, yDir, zDir);
var ellipse = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
ellipse.lookAt(direction);
ellipse.position.set( xPos, yPos, zPos);
ellipse.translateOnAxis(direction, distance);
```

Comment: We're going to need more information. We don't know what any of your position, direction, or distance variables are. Please consider creating a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to demonstrate the problem and give us a basis for fixing it.

Answer (score -2):

Your pasted code is buggy.

You're missing a ) on your applyMatrix line.

Are you using a debugger and observing console errors/warnings?

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: If the bug is the missing ), then it is an answer. Thanks for the downvote though.